# How can I programmatically summarize a tbl using different by-variables?

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to rewrite the code below using a loop to iterate over the by-variables 'a' and 'b'. How can I do that?

```
set.seed(1234)
mydata <- as.tbl(data.frame(a=1:12, b=runif(12), x=rnorm(12)))
mydata

library(dplyr)
library(Hmisc)

mydata %>%
  mutate(feature=cut2(a, g=3)) %>% 
  group_by(feature) %>%  # group by quantiles of 'a'
  summarise(x=mean(x))

mydata %>%
  mutate(feature=cut2(b, g=3)) %>% 
  group_by(feature) %>%  # group by quantiles of 'b'
  summarise(x=mean(x))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `interp` from `lazyeval`.

```
library(lazyeval)
lapply(c('a', 'b'), function(var)
                mydata %>% 
                  mutate_(feature=interp(~cut2(v1, g=3), v1=as.name(var))) %>% 
                          group_by(feature) %>%
                  summarise(x=mean(x)) )
```